# Running Python File in Terminal

Tags: command-line, python

Trying to learn how to run my scripts through Ubuntu's terminal regularly.  That being said I am familiar with `bash`, `wget`, and `awk` being called but how do I call python files to run in the terminal?  I would like to learn this but I am unsure on where to research it.  I have a `.pyw` file that references several `.py` files in a folder.

Comment: Differential case in the following because the original title too general including it  - about running python script in terminal to call 
a function https://stackoverflow.com/q/25837063/54964

Answer (score 106, accepted):

#### Option 1: Call the interpreter

- For Python 2: `python <filename>.py`
- For Python 3: `python3 <filename>.py`

#### Option 2: Let the script call the interpreter

1. Make sure the first line of your file has `#!/usr/bin/env python`.
2. Make it executable - `chmod +x <filename>.py`.
3. And run it as `./<filename>.py`

Comment: what is the reason, that when I want to run my .py it works only work with your method option 1, and the second gives a syntax error?

Comment: what if you want to open a new python file??

Answer (score 10):

Just prefix the script's filename with `python`. E.g.:

```
python filename.py
```

Answer (score 6):

It's also worth mentioning that by adding a `-i` flag after `python`, you can keep your session running for further coding. Like this:

```
python -i <file_name.py>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
python <filename.py>
```

pyw should run in the same manner, I think. You can also start an interactive console with just

```
python
```

Also, you can avoid having to invoke python explicitly by adding a shebang at the top of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

... or any number of variations thereof

Answer (score 2):

First run following command

```
chmod +x <filename>.py
```

Then at the top of the script, add `#!` and the path of the Python interpreter:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

If you would like the script to be independent of where the Python interpreter lives, you can use the `env` program. Almost all Unix variants support the following, assuming the Python interpreter is in a directory in the user's `$PATH`:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
```

Answer (score 2):

Change directories using `cd` to the directory containing the .py and run one of the following two commands:

```
python <filename>.py  # for Python 2.x  
python3 <filename>.py # for Python 3.x
```

Alternatively run one of the following two commands:

```
python /path/to/<filename>.py  # for Python 2.x  
python3 /path/to/<filename>.py # for Python 3.x
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using the command `python3` instead of `python`. If the script was written in Python3, and you try to run it with Python2, you could have problems. Ubuntu has both; changing the program name to `python3` (instead of replacing `python`) made this possible. Ubuntu needs v2.7 (as of  2/16/2017) so DON'T delete or remove Python2, but keep them both. Make a habit of using Python3 to run scripts, which can run either.

Comment: -1 Python 3 cannot run Python 2 scripts (with few exceptions).

Comment: My bad, your right. Thats probably why Ubuntu still uses python 2. Sorry wjandrea, thanks for correcting me.