# Terminal python _tkinter

Tags: command-line, python

I asked [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244378/run-python-in-terminal#comment303234_244378) question on how to get python to work in my Ubuntu Terminal.  After trying `python file.pyw`.  I was then given this error in the terminal: `importerror: no module named _tkinter, please install the python-tk package`.  I searched for this in google and ran accross [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4783810/install-tkinter-for-python) on stackoverflow.  However when i run that in the terminal I get

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied_
E: Unable to lock administration directory, are you root?  I am root.
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run this command as super user. Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk
```

This should fix your problem. The magic extra thing to type is the **sudo** command. This will trigger a password prompt and after you've correctly entered your password the command following `sudo` (in this case `apt-get install python-tk`) will be run under administrative privileges.

Comment: Hmm, was this really the issue? OP states "I am root." in the question.

Comment: Any better suggestion? Or do you think that the fact that he accepted my answer isn't obvious enough? To reproduce the error, simply enter the command in your terminal without `sudo` and see what happens :-)

Comment: Should have commented to the OP instead, sorry. If this worked, then the OP *wasn't* root.