# How do I run Python code as a script?

Tags: python

I need help running python in ubuntu

I can run python without a problem in my terminal
but when I create a `.py` file I can't get it to run.

Comment: So how are you trying?

Comment: thats what i try to find out

Comment: There are many ways, depending on if the file is executable or not, with shebang or not. Will see if I can quickly find a dupe with an overview.

Comment: Follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/304896 This will also make you program double-click-able.

Comment: whats shebang??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: got it thx dudes

Comment: @BitcoinAustria if (either) one of the answers solved your problem, would you consider accepting it, a.o. for clarity reasons? (The big "V" below the up/down arrows). It also prevents the question from re-appearing as "unanswered".

Answer (score 12):

How it works (examples for `python2`, for `python3`, replace all occurrences of `python` by `python3`):

1. `python /path/to/script.py`

   - works if file is either executable or not
   - shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) in the head of the script is good practice, but not needed
2. `/path/to/script.py`

   - works if script is executable
   - shebang is needed (`#!/usr/bin/env python`)
3. `script.py`

   - works if script is in [$PATH](https://askubuntu.com/a/551993/72216)
   - script needs to be executable
   - filename needs to have extension
   - shebang is needed (`#!/usr/bin/env python`)
4. `script`

   - works if script is in [$PATH](https://askubuntu.com/a/551993/72216)
   - script needs to be executable
   - filename should have no extension
   - shebang is needed (`#!/usr/bin/env python`)

#### A bit more information: precedence of command, shebang or extension?

The shell can get its information on how to run a script from two sources (in order of precedence):

- The language information in the command: `python <script>`
- The shebang, in the first line of the script: `#!/usr/bin/env python`

The language extension however does not play a role(!).

A few examples:

1. A `bash` script, correct (language) information in the command, *incorrect* shebang, *incorrect* extension:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env python
   echo 'Monkey eats banana'
   ```

   ran with:

   ```
   $ sh /path/to/script.py
   > Monkey eats banana
   ```

   runs correctly, the information in the command takes precedence over both the shebang and the extension.
2. An (executable) `python` script, ran with *incorrect* extension, but a correct shebang:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env/python
   print "Monkey eats banana"
   ```

   ran with:

   ```
   $ /path/to/script.sh
   > Monkey eats banana
   ```

   runs correctly, the information in the shebang takes precedence over the extension.
3. An (executable) `python` script, with a correct extension, but without shebang (and without language information in the command):

   ```
   print "Monkey"
   ```

   Ran with the command:

   ```
   $ /path/to/script.py
   > Error: no such file "Monkey"
   ```

   does not run correctly, in spite of the language extension!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need to make it executable.

```
chmod +x /path/to/your/file.py
```

Answer (score 1):

To run a python script, use `python`:

```
python script.py
```

Comment: i created a small script with sublime and saved it as test.py if i try to run it in the terminal
python test.py   I get a message that it isnt found
test.py is saved on the desktop

Comment: @BitcoinAustria Because most likely terminal's current location is not `~/Desktop`, change its location to `~/Desktop`: in a terminal: `cd ~/Desktop`

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered here: [Running Python File in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244378/run-python-in-terminal)

If none of these work:

You can save your code as a script in gedit with a .py file extension ie.`exampleFile.py`

But on the first line add `#!/usr/bin/python` and save.

Make the script executable by entering

```
chmod +x exampleFile.py
```

into the terminal.

(I usually save scripts in a separate directory and call the directory in the terminal via `cd exampleDirectory` and then execute scripts in that specific directory)

[also you can check if the script is in your directory by entering the `l` command in the terminal to list the files in that directory and the script should be green if it executable]

Then you can call the script to be ran in the terminal:

```
python exampleFile.py
```

You can replace `python` with `python3` in all the areas that `python` was listed, if you'd rather prefer that version

In addition, you can use `vim` or other third party software to write and run python scripts if none of these work.