# Why does Python in Linux require the line #!/usr/bin/python?

Tags: python, scripts

Pretty simple question: In Linux, why does Python require the line

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

at the start of a python file, since Windows doesn't?

**What does it do? 'cause the description "Links to Python" is a bit vague...**

Comment: The answers below are all correct, none of them address why Windows does not need this line.  Windows depends upon the extension of the file (the part after the `.`) to determine what kind of file it is.  Even Windows is moving away from this:  examine the first few lines of the Microsoft Word file, and it will state that it is in fact, a Microsoft Word file.

Comment: @CharlesGreen the old format that was used for Word documents (`.doc`) included a magic header that confirmed the filetype - just like the `MZ` at the beginning of executable files. The format that Word now uses (`.docx`) is basically a ZIP file with a different extension.

Comment: Even the new docx format includes about byte 130 that the document is a word document, in xml format

Comment: The elephant in the room is that you should NEVER use /usr/bin/python unless you are compatible with python 2 and 3. Reason: arch symlinks it to python3, a move which is acknowledged by the PSF, who recommend against it themselves.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/590410/how-do-i-run-python-code-as-a-script

Comment: It's implied, but not stated explicitly in the answers below that **it's not required**.  It's required if you want to execute the script just from ts own name.  You can always run `python myscript.py` instead.

Comment: @CharlesGreen we are not suppose to know why windows does not ;-) That is up to SO.

Comment: @YetAnotherUser It's been six years and eleven months since Python 3 was released, at this point I feel people would be better off defaulting to 3 and explicitly specifying the use of 2 when necessary.

Comment: @ChrisH Similarly, since you can change Windows' extension-based behavior, sometimes you need to explicitly run Python scripts using `python <script>` anyway. I used to set the default program to run for `.py` files to `gvim` when I was developing in Python on Windows.

Comment: The shebang is a [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29); the linked wikipedia entry says (in part) *Unix or Linux scripts may start with a ["shebang"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) (`#!`, `23` `21`) followed by the path to an interpreter, if the interpreter is likely to be different from the one from which the script was invoked.*

Comment: @KyleStrand, I always run `python <script>` on windows, and usually when I'm running scripts I wrote under windows on Linux.  That may have something to do with the reason I write *python* scripts: for computer-management tasks I use bash (Linux) or a bizarre hybrid of .bat+bash (windows with cygwin), while my python tends to be data-related.

Comment: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` does the trick for me too

Answer (score 76, accepted):

*Python* does not have any such special requirement on Linux. It's the *program loader* on Unix/Linux that uses the "shebang" line, as it's called. This is actually a feature rather than a limitation, but we'll get to that in a moment. [The Wiki page on "shebang" has more details,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) but I'll try to give an overview as well as a comparison to Windows here.

**First, let's look at the situation on Windows:**

- When you attempt to open or run a file, Windows first examines the *extension* of that file. This is the *last* part of the filename starting with `.` In the case of Python files, this is typically `.py`.
- Windows looks up what action to take based on the file extension.

  - This information is recorded in the Windows registry; when Python is installed, it typically tells Windows that `.py` files should be opened using the newly-installed *application* Python (i.e. the Python interpreter).
  - Several file-types have built-in behaviors; for instance, executable files (such as the Python interpreter itself) must end in `.exe`, and `.bat` files are executed as Windows batch-scripts.
  - The action taken for a particular file-type is *customizable*. You can, for instance, tell Windows that instead of running `.py` files using `python.exe`, it should open them with some other program, such as the text editor `notepad.exe`.

    - In this case, in order to *run* a Python script, you would need to *manually* call `python <scriptname>.py` (or write a `.bat` file to do this for you).

Now, what happens if there's a shebang line (`#!/usr/bin/python` or `#!/usr/bin/env python`) at the top of the Python script? Well, since `#` is a comment line in Python, the Python interpreter just ignores it. This is one reason why most scripting languages used in the Unix/Linux world use `#` to start comment lines.

So it's a bit misleading to say that Windows "doesn't need" the `#!` line; Windows doesn't *see* the `#!` line, and in fact relies on the file-extension to tell it what to do. This has a couple of disadvantages:

- You *must* name Python scripts with `.py` at the end in order to have them automatically recognized as such.
- There's no easy way to distinguish Python2 scripts from Python3 scripts.
- As previously noted, if you change the default launch behavior for the `.py` file-type, Windows will no longer automatically run those scripts with Python. Note that this could be done unintentionally.

**Now, let's look at how Unix/Linux launches scripts:**

The first thing to note is that Unix/Linux, unlike Windows, isn't trying to "open" Python scripts using a particular program, at least conceptually; the OS *knows* that the script is something that can be executed because of something called the "execute bit" (which is outside the scope of this answer). So, if you accidentally type `#!/usr/bin/pthon` instead of `#!/usr/bin/python`, you'll get an error message that includes this text:

```
/usr/bin/pthon: bad interpreter: No such file or directory.
```

The word "interpreter" gives us a clue about the role of the shebang line (though technically the specified program can be something other than an interpreter, such as `cat` or a text editor). When you attempt to execute a file, here's what happens:

- The Unix/Linux program loader looks at the first two bytes of that file; if these two bytes are `#!`, then the loader interprets the remainder of the shebang line (excluding the shebang itself) as a command to launch an *interpreter* with which to run the file contents as a script.
- The program loader launches the specified interpreter, feeding it the *path* of the original file as an argument.

This has a couple of advantages:

- The script-writer has more control over which interpreter will be used (which solves the Python2/Python3 issue) and can sometimes pass an extra argument to the interpreter (see the Wiki page for details).
- The filename of the script is *ignored*, so you can name Python scripts whatever you want.

Note, finally, that Unix/Linux does *not* **need** the shebang line in order to run a Python script. Recall that all the shebang line actually does is allow the program loader to *select* an interpreter. But just as in Windows, this can be done manually:

```
python <myscript>
```

Comment: On Windows you could easily have `.py2` and `.py3` extensions for Python 2 / Python 3 scripts. So both Linux (+x bit) and Windows (file extension) need metadata in the filesystem. The main difference is that the +x bit is more easily lost in transit. This is not necessarily a downside.

Comment: @MSalters The execute bit also has a lot less information encoded in it. And note that you might have multiple Python2 interpreters on a given system (there was a similar situation with Ruby and other languages at a previous job of mine); dealing with this via the shebang line is nearly trivial, whereas the situation on Windows gets substantially less tractable the more you attempt to manage multiple similar file-types.

Comment: Also, does the extension really count as "metadata"? It's just part of the filename.

Comment: The metadata of a file includes the whole filename, creation time, access bits, etc. Only the content itself is data instead of metadata. As for the "multiple interpreters", that is indeed a real problem and exactly why it _shouldn't_ be in the shebang line. What if you have `/usr/bin/i686/python` and `/usr/bin/amd64/python` ? Perfectly reasonable, but it breaks python scripts that have a hardcoded assumption on `/usr/bin/python`. The choice of interpreter is not a choice of the script writer but of the script user, The script writer only gets to choose the language (dialect).

Comment: @MSalters Well, that's what `/usr/bin/env`, is for, along with env-setup scripts. What's the Windows version of this? Running a `regedit` script right before you launch a `.py` file to ensure that you get the interpreter you want?

Comment: right click, "open with".

Comment: Great answer. Shouldn't be "[...] if these two bytes are #!, then the loader interprets the **rest of the** entire first line [...]" ?

Comment: @Rmano Thanks, and good point. I've clarified.

Answer (score 43):

The line you've indicated is used to tell the computer what program / interpreter to use when running the file/script directly, and any arguments that should be passed to that program when the script runs.  This is not, however, a requirement of *Python*, it's a requirement of the linux kernel/system if you intend to run the script directly (and not pass it to Python by the below syntax).

It is not needed if you are going to execute `python script.py` or similar.  It is only needed if you intend to run the script/file directly, without also providing the interpreter to use (such as `python`).

---

For a Bash script, it would have something like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash [optional Bash arguments]
# Bash script code here
...
exit 0;
```

This would indicate to the system that, when this runs, it should be run via `/bin/bash` which is one of the shells / shell-script languages on the system.

---

For Python code, though, here, you're going to be wanting to have the executable file run via Python, so you tell it what interpreter you intend to have run in it.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python [optional Python arguments]
# Python code here
...
exit()
```

This, like for Bash, indicates that `/usr/bin/python` should be used (this is likely Python 2 or Python 3, depending on your individual system configurations).

---

In this way, you can run `./filename.py` or `./executable` or `./scripttorun` directly.

Without that line at the beginning, and assuming you have set the file/script to be executable, and assuming you're working with a Python script, you would have to run `python filename.py` or similar if you did not have the `#!/usr/bin/python` line.  (For a Bash script, you would have to do `bash script.sh`, or similar for other scripts/languages, such as Perl, Ruby, etc.)

<sub>Syntax highlighting above is language-specific in each section, although it doesn't really matter.</sub>

Comment: An interesting thing to add would be that it's possible to specify additional parameters after the shebang itself, in most of the cases in the same way as if the interpreter was called directly (`#!/bin/bash -x`, `#!/usr/bin/perl -lan`, etc).

Comment: @kos: I think you can specify exactly one extra argument, which has been a PITA when one (should) use `/usr/bin/env python` to get the correct python.

Comment: @progo Not sure what the problem with `env` is, but the problem seems to *not* be the number of arguments: `#!/usr/bin/perl -l -a -n` has three arguments but it works. Though again, I'm not able to grok the exact problem.

Comment: When explicitly calling an interpreter with the script as argument, there is no reason to have the latter start with `./`. In other words just `python filename.py` or `bash script.sh` will work fine. The only reason to include `./` is in a command name, when you want to tell the shell not to search in `$PATH` (which probably wont find files in the current directory) but take the path you specified as-is. But that does not apply to command arguments.

Comment: @kos: The problem could be in how `env` receives the rest of the arguments from kernel. They could all be presumed to be one large argument with no splitting-by-space performed. Sorry for articulation, I don't remember the details of this that well anymore

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I'm aware, however I use it to indicate 'this directory'.  I'll edit

Answer (score 17):

The line:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

is called the 'shebang' and it indicates the path to the interpreter binary that will be used to interpret the rest of the commands in the file. It is usually the first line of a script.

So the line `#!/usr/bin/python` indicates that the content of the file will be interpreted by the `python` binary located at `/usr/bin/python`.

Note that the shebang line is parsed by the kernel and then the script will eventually be called as an argument:

```
python script_name
```

Similarly in case of `#!/bin/bash`:

```
bash script_name
```

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a hyphen in `shebang`. Since the word is formed from "hash" and "bang," your spelling is not very clear, since it looks like it's a combination of **"she"** and "bang".

Comment: You can call it `hashbang` (`#` = "hash") or `shebang` (`#` = "sharp"), depending on how you name the `#` character. However, `shebang` is indeed more common. @KyleStrand

Answer (score 7):

Technically, it doesn't require it. It requires a path to the environment where your script executes. Your future scripts would be better off to include /usr/bin/env then, specify python. This grantees that your script runs in the python environment no matter where python is installed. 
You want to do this for compatibility reasons, you cannot be sure the next person you share your code with will have python installed in usr/bin/python, or that they will have permissions to those system files.

[Here is a similar Q&A from stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670303/purpose-of-usr-bin-python3).

What that looks like in your script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

I also see some concern for how to specify python3. Here is how to do it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Answer (score 5):

In Linux, Python may or may not require the `#!` (shebang) line. This depends on how the Python codes are handled, either running the codes in Python interactive mode or in a Python script.

**Python interactive mode** allows the user to type and run Python codes directly, which does not require the shebang line. To run the interactive mode, open a Terminal and type `python` for Python 2.X or `python3` for Python 3.X.

```
$  python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 

$  python3
Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:33:09) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

**Python script** allows the user to write and save the Python codes in a plain text file, then run the codes later. This may or may not require the shebang line. However, there are two known reasons when the shebang line is required for using Python script in Linux.

1. to run Python codes in an executable script i.e. defines how the codes should be run and using what interpreter;
2. to run Python codes with respect to specific version of Python i.e. run codes that are compatible with either Python 2.X or Python 3.X only

### Practice with Python scripts

Below are the list and content of files, which I have used to show cases that `#!` (shebang) line is required or not required.

```
$  ls -ln *.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000  94 Dec 14 18:37 hello1.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1000 1000 116 Dec 14 18:37 hello2e.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 116 Dec 14 18:37 hello2.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1000 1000 117 Dec 14 18:37 hello3e.py
-rwxrwxr-x 1 1000 1000 120 Dec 14 18:37 hello3m.py
-rw-rw-r-- 1 1000 1000 117 Dec 14 18:37 hello3.py

$  file *.py
hello1.py:  ASCII text
hello2e.py: Python script, ASCII text executable
hello2.py:  Python script, ASCII text executable
hello3e.py: Python script, ASCII text executable
hello3m.py: Python script, UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) text executable
hello3.py:  Python script, ASCII text executable
```

- `hello1.py` contains source code only.

  ```
  import sys
  sys.stdout.write("Hello from Python %s\n" % (sys.version,))
  print("Hello, World!")
  ```
- `hello2.py` contains source code and the shebang line.

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import sys
  sys.stdout.write("Hello from Python %s\n" % (sys.version,))
  print("Hello, World!")
  ```
- `hello2e.py` contains same as `hello2.py` and made executable.
- `hello3.py` contains same as `hello2.py`, except it is adapted to run with Python 3 by renaming the first line to `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.
- `hello3e.py` contains same as `hello3.py` and made executable.
- `hello3m.py` contains same as `hello3.py` and made executable, except saved with `Write Unicode BOM` option in the text editor i.e. Mousepad.

Beyond this point, user will be presented with two methods to run the Python scripts. Both methods have been demonstrated as below.

### Method 1: Run with Python program

Below are the commands and output when running the source code with Python 2 and Python 3.

```
$  python hello1.py
Hello from Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
Hello, World!

$  python3 hello1.py
Hello from Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:33:09) 
[GCC 4.8.4]
Hello, World!
```

Both versions of Python were able to run the script successfully. Hence, the shebang line is *not* required when running the Python script via `python` or `python3` command.

### Method 2: Run as Python script

Below are the commands and output when running the source code with the shebang line, which are adapted to neither, Python 2 and Python 3, including non-executable and executable cases.

```
$  ./hello1.py
bash: ./hello1.py: Permission denied

$  ./hello2.py
bash: ./hello2.py: Permission denied

$  ./hello3.py
bash: ./hello3.py: Permission denied

$  ./hello2e.py 
Hello from Python 2.7.6 (default, Jun 22 2015, 18:00:18) 
[GCC 4.8.2]
Hello, World!

$  ./hello3e.py 
Hello from Python 3.4.3 (default, Oct 14 2015, 20:33:09) 
[GCC 4.8.4]
Hello, World!
```

The first three scripts have failed because these scripts are non-executable, regardless of having the shebang line or not (For supporting proof, see **Additional example** below). The last two scripts have shebang line and are executable.

Apparently, a script that has been made executable is essentially useless without the shebang line. Hence, the shebang line is required and the script must be executable when running the Python codes in an executable script.

### When shebang does not work

In my prepared and tested example, running `hello3m.py` as an executable script has failed and returned an error.

```
$  ./hello3m.py 
./hello3m.py: line 1: #!/usr/bin/env: No such file or directory
```

This is a [known limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19065522) that shebang does not work or becomes invalid. When a file is saved as Unicode BOM (Byte Order Mark), it will fail to run normally as an executable Python script.

### Additional example

This additional example shall be treated as supporting proof only. User should avoid running this example, although the result is harmless.

I have created another file called `hello1e.py`, which contains same as `hello1.py` and made executable. Running this script returned a syntax error.

```
$  ./hello1e.py 
./hello1e.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"Hello from Python %s\n"'
./hello1e.py: line 2: `sys.stdout.write("Hello from Python %s\n" % (sys.version,))'
```

When running this script, at first, the mouse cursor will be changed to a plus-sign and does nothing in appearance. The syntax error will not be shown until I made a click on the Desktop or Terminal window. Then, this script will create a `sys` file in the same directory as the script.

```
$  file sys
sys: PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0, Level 1
```

The `sys` file has been identified as PostScript file, without file extension. This file can be opened in document viewer i.e. Evince, and the file actually contained a screenshot of the window that I had clicked earlier. In my experience, the file can be as large as few Megabytes.

Once again, the shebang line is required and the script must be executable when running the Python script as an executable script. Otherwise, the script will misbehave as described above.

### Additional notes

The term "made executable" or "must be executable" refers to the permission to run the script. This is done by running `chmod +x FILENAME` command in Terminal, or by checking the option "Allow this file to run as a program" or something similar in the **Properties** window, within a file manager.

While other existing answers had covered almost everything, this answer has taken different approach by using practical examples to explain the matter. The code syntax have been written with care, such that the examples could be run with either Python 2 or Python 3, as it is.

The Python codes have been adapted from [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html) and [Using Python on Unix platforms](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html), with additional one-line code of the ubiquitous "Hello, World!" program.

All codes and commands have been fully tested and works in Xubuntu 14.04 system, which had Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 installed by default.

Answer (score 4):

It means that when that file is executed your computer knows to execute it with the program `/usr/bin/python`, that's how you tell it apart from another language, such as bash where you would do `#!/bin/bash`. This is so that you can simply run:

```
./[file-to-execute]
```

And it will know which file to execute it with, rather than you yourself having to specify with something like:

```
python ./[file-to-execute].py
```

The `#!` part is commonly refereed to as a *shebang*, *crunch bang* or *hashbang*.

Comment: Also a hashbang.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several versions of Python installed, `/usr/bin/env` will ensure the interpreter used is the first one on your environment's `$PATH`. The alternative would be to hardcode something like `#!/usr/bin/python`;

In Unix, an executable file that's meant to be interpreted can indicate what interpreter to use by having a `#!` at the start of the first line, followed by the interpreter (and any flags it may need).

This rule only applicable for UNIX based system.

Answer (score 0):

Helpful for OS's like Linux where Python 2.x is still the standard, but most people also download 3.x.

2.x would run by default. So my 3.x code, I prefix with

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

so that 3.x runs the code.  I can even specify down to the minor revision (python 3.x.y.z) if I so chose to have beta releases or just slightly older versions.