# How do i get the Python Interpreter

Tags: lubuntu, python

I have Lubuntu. Like version 14.04 i think. Its supported till 2019 i do know that. I have python installed i think. I type "python3" into the terminal and it just allows me to code in the terminal. I can't find the interpreter anywhere. Is the interpreter what I want to be able to compile the code, and write multiple lines of code?

Comment: related [run-python-in-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/244378/run-python-in-terminal)

Comment: I have the feeling you are looking for Idle, a python IDE? Python is an interpreted language btw.

Comment: Hi voyager, just curious, but did you take a look at idle? I am pretty much it is what you are looking for: type your code or script, press f5 to test-run the code and check for errors. Typing into gedit and check via terminal seems a clumsy detour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

open or create any file with name `.py` for example

```
gedit test.py
```

write code to this file

```
print('Hello, world!')
```

save and close file and execute code like:

```
python3 test.py
```

Answer (score 4):

The Python3 interpreter is located under `/usr/bin/python3.x`.

For future reference you can easily find `python` or any other executable locations by using the `whereis` command :

```
whereis python3
```

Answer (score -1):

You could download a text editor such as gedit. It will allow you to program in the editor with certain functionality such as bracket matching and syntax highlighting. To install, run:

```
sudo apt-get install gedit
```

Once it's done, you can open the program and start coding.