# force to use Python 3

Tags: apt, bash, scripts, python

i want to port Python Scripts to python 3. How can i force Ubuntu to use python 3 instead of python 2 which is installed, as well.

Due to the size of the project, i'd prefer not to write something like 'use python3' inside the scripts.
Deinstalling python 2 isn't an option too, because there are to many dependencies.

So, can i remove Python 2 from the path for a while or something, so that python scripts are called with Python 3 by default.

Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: What you actually say is you won't use a shebang (which defines the version to use). *Due to the size of the project*??? Seems totally unclear to me. Either use a shebang (script = executable), or call the script with `python3 <script>`

Comment: To elaborate,  you only need a shebang in the main script that's being called to start the program. All other files that are imported fon't need this. So, like others said, the size of your project doesn't matter.

Comment: Do it like https://askubuntu.com/questions/244378/run-python-in-terminal but replace every occurrence of `python` with `python3`.

Answer (score 4):

## Option 1:

Just put `#!/usr/bin/env python3` on top of each script file.

> Due to the size of the project, i'd prefer not to write something like 'use python3' inside the scripts.

It's just one line, it can't increase the size of the project much. Writing this is a *standard* UNIX and Python convention.

## Option 2:

Just call the script with `python3` instead of `python`.