# How to move Only the files in current folder to a sub folder?

Tags: command-line, files, mv

I don't have to move the folders, only the files.

I have tried `mv *` but this command moves the folders also.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to move everything except directories from `$SOURCE_DIR` to `$TARGET_DIR`, you can use this command:

```
find "$SOURCE_DIR" -maxdepth 1 -not -type d -exec mv -t "$TARGET_DIR" -- '{}' +
```

Explained in detail:

- `find`: The find search for files in a directory
- `$SOURCE_DIR`: The directory to search in
- `-maxdepth 1`: Do not look inside subdirectories
- `-not -type d`: Ignore directories

  - You could also use `-type f` if you only want to copy things that are strictly files, but I prefer the above because it also catches everything that's neither a file nor a directory (in particular symbolic links)
- `-exec mv -t "$TARGET_DIR" -- '{}' +`: Run the command `mv -t "$TARGET_DIR" -- FILES...` where `FILES...` are all the matching files (thanks @DavidFoerster)

Comment: `find ... -exec mv -t "$TARGET_DIR" -- '{}' +` would be safer (in case `$TARGET_DIR` is no directory or the match starts with `-`) and more efficient (because it doesn't spawn a new sub-process for every matched file).

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thanks, updated (also learnt something new today!)

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to mv only your files.First go to the your directory and use this command, replace $TARGET with your target directory path. If you want to copy your files replace `mv` with `cp`.

```
find . -type f -exec mv {} $TARGET \;
```

if I explain this, `find . -type f` means select all files and `-exec mv {} $TARGET \;` means execute `mv` command to all selected items.

---

Previous answer has a error.. it `mv` all files inside sub directories also. The quick fix is use `-maxdepth 1`. Then it not recursively `mv` files within sub directories. Below is the correct one..

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} $TARGET \;
```

Comment: I don't think the questioner wants this!  It would also move all files in any subdirectories into that same target directory.  The `-type f` doesn't prevent recursion.

Comment: @MartinThornton thank you for your suggestion.. i will edit my answer...

Answer (score 4):

If you're using zsh instead of bash, you can do this:

```
mv "$SOURCE"/*(.) "$TARGET"
```

The `(.)` at the end is called a glob qualifier; the `.` inside specifically means to only match regular files.

Doing a `mv *(.) "$target"` is quick and practical. However, if you're doing this as part of a script, you might want to consider instead writing something like what Frxstrem and David Forester suggested, `mv -t "$target" -- *(.)`, to better handle corner cases that might arise in other people's usage.

Comment: As David Forester pointed out on my answer, `mv -t "$TARGET" -- "$SOURCE"/*(.)` would be safer (in case `"$TARGET"` starts with a `-` or is not a directory). I do like the zsh solution though!

Answer (score 3):

#### Python approach

When dealing with files recursively, `find` is the way to go. In this particular case it's not necessary, but can be used with `-maxdepth 1` as other answers show.

Simple python command can do it as well. Here's an example:

```
$ tree
.
├── a_directory
└── a_file

$ python -c "import os,shutil;fl=[f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)];                                      
> map(lambda x:shutil.move(x,'./a_directory'),fl)"

$ tree
.
└── a_directory
    └── a_file

1 directory, 1 file
```

#### How this works:

- `fl=[f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]` iterates over all  items that  `os.listdir('.')` finds and we test whether the item is a file using `os.path.isfile()` function.
- Once `fl` file list is built, we use `map()` function. This function takes two arguments - a function, and a list of items; it will perform the function that we gave it per each file in a list. Thus here we have`lambda x:shutil.move(x,'./a_directory')` as anonymous function which will move a a given file to a given directory, and then we have the `fl` - the list of files that we built up.

For readability and general usage, we could also rewrite this as a general python script, which takes two arguments - source directory and destination subdirectory.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile,realpath
from os.path import join as joinpath
from shutil import move
from sys import argv

# this is script's full path
script=realpath(__file__)
# get all items in a given directory as list of full paths
fl=[ joinpath(argv[1],f) for f in listdir(argv[1]) ] 
# filter out script itself ( just in case) and directories
fl_filtered = [ f for f in fl if isfile(f) and not script == realpath(f) ]
# Uncomment this in case you want to see the list of files to be moved
# print(fl_filtered)
# move the list of files to the given destination
for i in fl_filtered:
     move(i,argv[2])
```

And the usage is like so:

```
$ tree
.
├── a_directory
├── a_file
└── files2subdir.py

1 directory, 2 files

# Notice: the script produces no output unless you uncomment print statement
$ ./files2subdir.py "." "./a_directory"                                                                                  

$ tree
.
├── a_directory
│   └── a_file
└── files2subdir.py
```

Comment: Here's another [Python approach](http://askubuntu.com/a/899332/3712)

Answer (score 2):

To move everything except directories from `source-dir` directory to `destination-dir` directory, in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""Usage: mv-files <source-dir> <destination-dir>"""
import shutil
import sys
from pathlib import Path

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    sys.exit(__doc__)  # print usage & exit 1
src_dir, dest_dir = map(Path, sys.argv[1:])
for path in src_dir.iterdir():
    if not path.is_dir():
        shutil.move(str(path), str(dest_dir / path.name))
```

See [Running Python File in Terminal](https://askubuntu.com/q/244378/3712).

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I don't see such requirement in pep-8 and (according to the example there) it is actually the exact opposite: `import mypackage` before `from mypackage import ...`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy don't confuse the special `from __future__` imports and ordinary `from pathlib` imports.

Comment: Yeah, looks like I've misread that part.  No, you're right, `import module` should be first (which is library and third party imports) `from module import object` should be last ( local/library specific)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
mv *.*
```

this will work as long as your folders don't have extensions.